# Function for press enter before a sleep

Tags: bash, function, shell, sleep

I do a tic tac toe code and I wanted to add a function for pressing "enter" when the code shows the rules. For now, I have a sleep 10 and the rule disappears and the game starts, but I want to press enter and the rule disappears, not with a sleep.

```
##############FONCTION MENU##############
menu() {  
  clear
  echo "######################### Morpion Gang #########################

Voici les règles : Pour gagner la partie faut aligner de manière 
horizontal,vertical ou en diagonal les symboles suivant : X et O 

La partie va commencer dans 10 secondes"
sleep 10
}
```

Comment: You're probably looking for the `-t timeout` option to Bash [`read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read).

Comment: Yeap i do -read with -t 10 thank

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```sh
read -p 'Hit Enter to start.'
```

You can combine this with the `-t` option if you also want a timeout.

Anything the user types will be stored in the variable named `REPLY` (the default variable for the read command).